# Como dar efecto de voltear carta con css3

Tags: javascript, css3

Buenas noches, trato de realizar un efecto de voltear carta, pero cuando lo realizo mi imagen trasera me aparece al reves, tengo este codigo.

```
.flip{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform: perspective(600px);
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip:hover{

    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg) translateX(100%);
}
```

Y se lo estoy aplicando a esta imagen:

```
<img class ="flip" id = "cara" onMouseOver="cambiar()" onMouseOut = "volver()" width="100" height="150" src="carta1.jpg" onclick="cartasDeJugador()">
```

funciones js

```
function cambiar () {
    if(mazo[mazo.length-1] === undefined)
        iniciarJuego();
    else
        document.getElementById('cara').src = mazo[mazo.length-1];
 }

 function volver () {
  document.getElementById('cara').src = "carta1.jpg";
 }
```

quisiera que la imagen trasera apareciera correcta y no al reves

Comment: aqui tienes un [tutorial en ingles](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)(sencillo) de como hacer `flip`con `css3` tanto vertical como horizontal

Comment: Podrías marcarla como respondida? Saludos

Comment: @DanielDíaz he visto tu reporte. El usuario lleva tiempo sin conectarse. Esperemos que se conecte y vea tu comentario. Un saludo

Answer (score 7):

Me he fijado en el enlace que a aportado el compañero lois6b y te he puesto [un ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/utgwf3oo/1/).

Como verás, lo que he hecho ha sido crear un `container` que hace referencia a una carta con una cara trasera y otra delantera, yo la he llamado así pero podrías ponerle la clase `carta` por ejemplo.

Si quieres compatibilidad con tablets iOS en Chrome deberás añadir la propiedad `-webkit-transition` junto a `transition`

```css
.front, .back, .container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}

.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.back {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="front" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/320/480/abstract" />
  <img class="back" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/320/480/cats" />
</div>
```

Comment: hahaha gracias, estaba muy vago como para convertilo en respuesta (+1)

Comment: Nada, tu link me ha ahorrado la google-búsqueda jaja